# REST API semantics for querying dates/times?

Tags: rest, datetime, express

I have a node.js application that stores many dates in a database.  They are stored in the ISO format, such as `'2016-11-02T16:30:12-04:00'`.

Some fields which are dates are just dates, other are date/times.  An example of a date/time would be "last modified" for a record, where a person's birthday is just a date.

The question is about best practices for storage and query patterns on these things.  Because a date always has a time, you must choose how to store for example a birthday.   [Following the 5 laws of API dates and times](http://apiux.com/2013/03/20/5-laws-api-dates-and-times/) this is of course done in UTC.

There are edge cases though where proper API behavior seems unclear.  Suppose someone submits a birthdate to the API of `'2016-11-02T16:30:12-04:00'`.   This is bad news, because a search like `/users?birthdate=2016-11-02` will fail, as that date will get converted to `'2016-11-02T00:00:00Z'` and fail to match in the DB.  What then should correct behavior be?

1. When someone `POST`s a user, convert date fields into dates at midnight UTC, and then have the convention that querying birthdates should assume the same?
2. Convert date queries for certain fields into implicit ranges, i.e. searching for `2016-11-02` is really looking for `2016-11-02T00:00:00Z <= x <= 2016-11-02:23:59:59Z`?
3. Match only on the exact moment, and rely on the client to know that a birthday of `'2016-11-02T16:30:12-04:00'` really means 4:30PM EST, and does not mean just on November 2nd?

What's the established pattern / best practice here for distinguishing between dates and datetimes?

Answer (score 1):

I have been studying REST best practices and standards a lot for a while and I can't recall reading anything about that, but for the usage of ISO standard. From your description it seems to be something that really depends on the application and its use-cases.

I would go for your option #2: if a GET request comes with a date but no time, consider it a query for the whole day, and do the "conversion" in your GET response server code. Maybe you'd want to support both a "date" and a separate "time" query string parameters if the precise time might matter occasionally. This can also help you to keep clients "unaware" of the database storage format you choose, and may even allow you to support localized date formats.

Comment: it seems fundamental to javascript dates that they always come with times too, whether wanted or not, right?   Hopefully people don't actually store three fields (year month day) and then compare on that.   I wonder how else this is addressed, as I can't be the first person to have this problem.  I think it stems from confusing a date with a date time.

Comment: I don´t know if this is really _that_ mandatory for JavaScript (I believe it is not, it really sounds sounds as an app-bound issue). Look at [https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#date] , 3.3.3: _"date represents top-open intervals of exactly one day in length on the timelines of dateTime..."_. Both data and dateTime are "legal" and recognized. Try to identify the most common use-cases for that search; they will probably tell you the best approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the usage of UTC, which implies that there's a time associated with it. There's not, a birthdate is considered (in iCalendar) a 'floating date' and does not have a specific time associated with it.

If your birthdate is November 3rd, and you move to Australia, your birthdate does not actually change to November 2nd, because your birthdate does not have a time, does not have a timezone and is the same where ever you are in the world.

The solution is simple. If you allow users to submit a date/time for birthday searches, then you should just 'cut off' the time and timezone. Assume that you're only going to be using the date portion and just search your database based on that.

Ideally you don't allow users to submit a time at all though. I think this just creates confusion. Just force api clients to submit a date only.

Those '5 laws' are an extreme over-simplification and don't apply to many situations.